# How can I center a div?

Tags: css, sass

As you could see the total height is 1000px, inside their 3 boxes which give 600px height in total. What I'm trying to do is to make the last box be in the middle between box2 and end of container. Good solution would be `margin: "auto 0"` to `box3`, but it doesn't work.

How can I get that result?

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: black;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.box2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.box3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you set `width: 100%` when it's the default for divs? Anyways, `.box3` will take up the whole width of the parent `.container` div, so trying to center it wont do anything.

Comment: If you know it's going to be 1000 / 200 / 200 / 200, you could just put `margin-top: 200px` on box3?

Comment: NO, I don't know the width, that's just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="box1"></div>
     <div class="box2"></div>
     <div class="center">
          <div class="box3"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

It would be easiest to do something like this, just give the center class the following styles:

```
.center{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: I'll try that. Seems good

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Flexbox:

```
.center-content {
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[example](https://codepen.io/sean-conkie/pen/GRBNegZ)

Comment: NO, that's not what I meant. Box1 and Box2 stays as is, but BOX3 should be centered between box2 and end of container. Basically center BOX3 within remaining height in container

Comment: Misread your question, RamenNoodle93 already answered  but I’ve corrected my answer also